# span class="caret" in button-toggle disappears after website gets load in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing an issue regarding caret arrow in bootstrap.

Dropdown arrow is supposed to be as default appears in the box. But apparently it is not showing.

Arrow only comes when my site is loading but it gets disappear after the site gets load.

Here is the HTML of my page. I also included the dropdown js to:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="label-head">Goods Type</label>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <input type="hidden" id="cargoTypeId" />
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle sales-button" type="button"
              data-toggle="dropdown">
        Select Goods Type
        <span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu sales-dropdown" id="goodsTypeList">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 right-float">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="label-head">Body Type</label>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <input type="hidden" id="bodyTypeId" />
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle sales-button body-type-value" type="button"
              data-toggle="dropdown">
        Select Body Type
        <span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu sales-dropdown" id="bodyTypeList">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is Javascript

```
getGoodsType = function (){
$.ajax({
    url: serviceURl + "v1/cargo-types",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: "",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.cargo_types != null) {
            var list = "";
            $.each(response.cargo_types, function(index, val) {
                list += "<li name='cargo" +val.id +"' >" +val.cargo_type_name +"</li>"
            });
            $("#goodsTypeList").append(list);
            $("#goodsTypeList li").click(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('name');
                id = id.replace("cargo","");
                $("#cargoTypeId").val(id);
                console.log(id);
                $(this).parents(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle").html($(this).text() + '<span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>');

            });
        }
    },
    statusCode: {
        409: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#account-exists").modal("show");
        },
        500: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#something-went-wrong").modal("show");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        $("body").unmask("");
    }
});
};

getBodyType = function (){
$.ajax({
    url: serviceURl + "v1/body-types",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: "",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.body_types != null) {
            var list = "";
            $.each(response.body_types, function(index, val) {
                list += "<li name='body" +val.id +"'>" +val.body_type_name +"</li>"
            });
            $("#bodyTypeList").append(list);
            $("#bodyTypeList li").click(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('name');
                id = id.replace("body","");
                $("#bodyTypeId").val(id);
                console.log($(this).parents(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle"));
                $(this).parents(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle").html($(this).text() +'<span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>');
                });
        }
        getCompanyDetails();
    },
    statusCode: {
        409: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#account-exists").modal("show");
        },
        500: function () {
            $("body").unmask("");
            $("#something-went-wrong").modal("show");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        $("body").unmask("");
    }
});
};
```

Comment: I am new to javascript. So, please can anyone suggest me the best solution for it?

Comment: Check your CSS codes as well. 

`$(this).parents(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle").html($(this).text() + '<span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>');`

Span is already in your html code. Are your sure you are not adding second time.

Comment: @ElnurIbrahim-zade. when i am refresh my website that arrow doesn't show but when i select another option from the  dropdown list the arrow appears in the box.

I am sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Maybe because you bind `$(this).parents(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle").html($(this).text() + '<span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>');` this code on ` click(function `.

`$("#goodsTypeList li").` **click(function** `(){
                var id = $(this).attr('name');
                id = id.replace("cargo","");
                $("#cargoTypeId").val(id);
                console.log(id);
                ` ** $(this).parents(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-toggle").html($(this).text() + '<span class="caret arrow-sales"></span>'); ** `

            });`

Comment: You should bind it before hand

Comment: Use development tools on browser to find whats happening :)